# Create Yammer network for an Organization

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, yammer

Can anyone help me on creating Yammer network for one of our client.
I have gone through so many links on google but most of the links are related to O365. Our client is not having O365. In future they want to integrate with SharePoint server 2013.
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what difficulty you are having.

You can sign up for Yammer for free, but you have little control over it unless you are on a paid tier.  Once someone with the @comaany address signs in, the Yammer space is created, and anyone with @company address can join.  The users will get an email message to confirm they have access thru that domain, and once verified will access to Yammer.

If you are familiar with SocialCast, Slack, or other social tools, they are all similar with how the "free" part of the service works.

Comment: We as SharePoint Admin want full control over our Yammer network and also want to enable SSO. So not sure how we can do that.

Comment: You have to purchase a subscription. I don't believe there is a stand-alone plan any longer, it's bundled with different Office365 SKU's.   Just pop over to one of the subscription information pages (  https://products.office.com/en-US/business/compare-office-365-for-business-plans ) and you'll get a chat popup.  You can ask them about licensing Yammer specifically